# How do you move out the toaster in Project Zomboid?

Tags: project-zomboid

So I mistakenly placed a toaster on the floor? (May be), instead of the kitchen platform and now it's not letting me access the storage behind it nor am I able to select it and move it around?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the "pick up object" menu item is not working?

Comment: @Yorik is it like I need to pick and move the entire object with the furniture moving option? cuz until now I was just trying to right click on it and see if I could move

Comment: Thanks, that worked... for my life I was not able to figure it out cuz I remember looted it using the right click menu and had also placed using the same but never used any furniture controls... thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to use furniture controls to move around the toaster and the right-click menu will not work to pick and place as I did while looting.